# How can a bash script detect support for window titling escape characters?

Tags: bash, terminal, xterm, escape-characters, window-title

I have a debug trap that runs every time I enter a command in bash that sets the window title to indicate what command is running.  I'm leaving out all the configuration details and boil it down to:

```
export PS1="\[\e]0;$GENERATED_WINDOW_TITLE\a\]$GENERATED_PROMPT"
```

This works incredibly well, with only one snag: if the bash shell is running in an environment that does not support this feature, the GENERATED_WINDOW_TITLE is printed on the screen with each prompt.  This happens any time I'm running bash from a non-X terminal.

How can bash tell if this escape sequence is supported?

Comment: I'm looking at "tput has_status_line" as a possible starting point, but all my terminals claim that this is not a known terminfo capability - despite documenting it as a boolean in terminfo.

Comment: I've updated the blog post on this topic, in case you're interested in the fun color prompt and status line stuff I was doing with this: http://www.foodini.org/permalink.cgi?link=20080816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a terminfo capability for that. In practice, testing the value of `TERM` should be good enough. That's what I do in my `.bashrc` and `.zshrc`, and I don't recall it being a problem.

```
case $TERM in
  (|color(|?))(([Ekx]|dt|(ai|n)x)term|rxvt|screen*)*)
    PS1=$'\e\]0;$GENERATED_WINDOW_TITLE\a'"$PS1"
esac
```

Comment: Heh heh.  I just plugged in an "if [ $TERM == "xterm" ];" but holy cow!  How did you pull that list of possibilities together?

Comment: @Sniggerfardimungus Right now, `grep -C5 title ~/.zshrc`. When I wrote it (last updated 2007)… I didn't leave a comment, so by observation I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the hack.  I've had trouble getting it to parse, though, and went with a simpler version that I'll build up over time as I find a need for more terminals.

Answer (score 2):

There is a terminfo entry which is (ab)used for this purpose, and has been the subject of more than one bug report suggesting that it be applied to various terminal descriptions.  Referring to `terminfo(5)`:

```
   has_status_line           hs     hs   has extra status
                                         line
   from_status_line          fsl    fs   return from status
                                         line
   to_status_line            tsl    ts   move to status line,
                                         column #1
```

these are explained in the section [*Status Lines*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Status-Lines):

> Some terminals with status lines need special sequences to
>   access the status line.   These  may  be  expressed  as  a
>   string with single parameter **`tsl`** which takes the cursor to
>   a given zero-origin column on the status line.

Offhand, the only terminal emulator which you are likely to be able to use which supports the feature as documented is [`kterm`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/kterm).

An *extension* would be appropriate.  The `screen` program documents a possible choice (but after inspecting what it *does* with the feature, that idea was discarded).  ncurses provides an extension which has been in the terminal database a [few years](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20131102), documented in the section on [XTerm Extensions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_X_T_E_R_M__Extensions_):

```
# TS is a string capability which acts like "tsl", but uses no parameter and
#    goes to the first column of the "status line".
```

Ultimately, anything that uses the feature would inherit from [`xterm+sl`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_sl):

```
# These building-blocks allow access to the X titlebar and icon name as a
# status line.  There are a few problems in using them in entries:
#
# a) tsl should have a parameter to denote the column on which to transfer to
#    the status line.
# b) the "0" code for xterm updates both icon-title and window title.  Some
#    window managers such as twm (and possibly window managers descended from
#    it such as tvtwm, ctwm, and vtwm) track windows by icon-name. Thus, you
#    don't want to mess with icon-name when using those window managers.
#
# The extension "TS" is preferable, because it does not accept a parameter.
# However, if you are using a non-extended terminfo, "TS" is not visible.
```

The (ncurses) [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) program can test this feature.